# How to store a specific float in Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am trying to follow a guide from Google on how to store location data ([here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html)), but, I need to convert this to ASP.NET MVC C# and having a little trouble setting up the class.

I have just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302293/how-do-i-represent-an-option-calculated-column-with-ef-code-first), and, I think it is similar, but, I can't really understand the solution.

I was wondering if anyone can help me on how to store a [10,6] float in the an Entity Framework Code First Generated database, or, a better way of storing longitude and latitude in EF.

Comment: If you can wait just a little you can use native support for spatial data, which will be in EF 4.2 which is in beta right now.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - always the way :( I will try to take a look at the beta... This really needs to go live within the next week and location search was just added last minute to the specifications - I have never done it before and am really struggling :(

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `decimal` instead of `float`? I think the range and precision will be enough.

You can always create a `decimal` property for storing and a `float` property that will use the other one and do the conversion if you need `float` in the rest of your app.